# Is it possible to run multiple x sessions with each functioning properly?

Tags: x11

I have tried running `startx` twice before and having two X sessions at once. However, I recall that time I tried it (which was on my Raspberry Pi) there were many strange bugs and errors. Are there consequences of running multiple X sessions at once?

Comment: There are certainly no consequences or problems if each X11 session is using different framebuffers. For example, you can run as many concurrent `Xvnc` sessions as you want. Can you clarify whether or not that's what you're doing?

Comment: What are frame buffers? I just run `startx` in two different virtual consoles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But bugs can happen. Video drivers are pretty complex, and running multiple X servers at once isn't very common so it doesn't get much testing.

Bugs, by definition, are unintended behavior. There's no fixed set of “consequences” of running multiple X sessions. If there wasn't a bug in your driver, it would work fine.

Comment: By "consequences" I did mean "bugs". Sorry if that wasn't clear.